# Why my scheduled crontab update is not working?

Tags: cron, root

As root, I've created a file called `update.bash` and saved it inside the `/root` folder... The content of the file is the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
apt update
apt -y upgrade
```

I gave this file execution permission with `chmod +x /root/update.bash`... Then using the command `crontab -e` (as root), I've added the following line on root's crontab:

```
0 1 * * *  /root/update.bash
```

This syntax schedules this script to run every day at 1 am, which is fine since it's a server that's always on. The problem here is that my update doesn't seem to be working even though I know this script runs every day as root, I know it doesn't work because there's usually a lot of accumulated updates on the system after some time I don't do it manually. In my view, scheduling `crontab` as root to run `apt update` and `apt -y upgrade` should work fine for automating updates... But it doesn't work, what am I missing? Is there any additional step I need to do to update the system with crontab?

Comment: You are reinventing the wheel - don't write your own solution, use `unattended-upgrades`. There might be questions `dpkg` has that your commandline does not answer.

Comment: What do your mails say? cron will usually mail the output to the user, which would alert you to issues like, oh, PATH not being set and apt not being found.

Comment: I don't know if it would change anything for your problem but in general you should use apt-get instead of apt in scripts